# Using Qt Quick 1 code model instead of Qt Quick 2. (M324)

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator

I am using Qt version  5.10.1 got this warning.
How do I resolve this.

[image]

**Edit:**

Tried to reset the model 
select Tools > QML/JS > Reset Code Model. not working. tried with second option but couldn't find the option .please see the below screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [List of JavaScript and QML Checks](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html#list-of-javascript-and-qml-checks):

> **M324**
>
> Warning
>
> Using Qt Quick 1 code model instead of Qt Quick 2
>
> The code model might be corrupt or the QML emulation layer might have
>   been built with a different Qt version than the one selected in the
>   build and run kit. For more information, [`see Resetting the Code Model`](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html#resetting-the-code-model)
>   and [`Running QML Modules in Qt Quick Designer`](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-modules-with-plugins.html#running-qml-modules-in-qt-quick-designer).

To reset the model as indicated by the [link](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-checking-code-syntax.html#resetting-the-code-model), you must do the following:

```
select Tools > QML/JS > Reset Code Model.
```

2nd Option:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also trying for the second option , but couldn't find the option in tools .I have editted the question with screen shot

Comment: @VineeshTP see my screenshots

Comment: I got the option from the Preference. I am using Mac version. Thank you.

Comment: @VineeshTP I find it strange, I'm using Qt Creator 4.6.1 on Linux, if it does not appear to Qt report, I think it's a bug.

Comment: I am using mac. I got this option from preference option.